# QTableWidget show scroll bar

Tags: c++, qt

I would like the horizontal scroll bar to appear whenever there is text eliding. Such that the user won't have to resize the whole GUI. How would I do this?

This is what I have coded:

```
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(1,QHeaderView::Stretch);
ui->tableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents();
```

I also tried enabling scrollbar to appear always, but scrolling to the very right doesn't do anything.

[image]

If I set `textElideMode` to `ElideNone` , the text from the 2nd column is partially hidden and no scrollbar appears.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QHeaderView::Stretch` will stretch the column width to the available space. Use `QHeaderView::ResizeToContents` to make the column wide enough to display the content, resulting in a horizontal scroll bar if necessary.

This will have a couple of side effects of which I'm not sure you want them.

- There will probably be no more ellipsis in the elided text.
- If all of the values in your Hash column are very small, then that column will be very thin, so there might be 'empty' space next to that column.